# mContext fragments and garbage collection

Tags: android

I am having the problem with fragments where I create

```
Context mContext = getActivity();
```

In my nested fragment constructor but after a long period of no use of my app mContext seems to be garbage collected and when I resume the activity the value is now null.

I was think about putting a mContext null check on the onResume of my fragment. Is this the best way to handle this error. This problem occurs in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Activity` is not visible, the `Activity` is going to the `onStop` method of its lifecycle, then the `Activity` can be garbage collected by the OS any time the OS feels like.

You shouldn't rely on the `Context` after the `Activity` is not visible.

Always get a fresh `Context` when you're resuming the `Activity` and don't rely on `NullPointer` checks when you shouldn't be getting a `NullPointer` in the first place ;-)

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html for reference.

**EDIT:** Quote from the last link:

> When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, it's no longer visible and should release almost all resources that aren't needed while the user is not using it. Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory.